# question on showing transitivity of a relation

Tags: relations

Define a relation on Z as xRy if |x−y|<1.

I have shown this relation is symetric and reflexive and i am pretty sure its 
transitive because this is the equality relation isnt it? thats my first question and my second is how to show it is transitive.

I attempted a direct proof but i dont know how to link the two inequalities together to get that |x−z|<1 (im trying to show if xRy and yRz then xRz).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! I am looking for the proof of this last property (transitivity).

Comment: Thanks, but its a relation on z so only for integer values

Comment: There are no integers satisfying this relation.

Comment: what about x=4 y=4?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say _distinct_. Modulo is non-negative; the only non-negative less than 1 is 0.

Comment: So is it transitive?

Answer (score 0):

If your relation is in fact on $\Bbb{Z}$, then $xRy$ is the same as writing $x=y$
because if $x\ne y$ then the distance between x and y is obviously larger than 1.
"=" is transistive thus R is also transistive because the two relations are equivalent

*Proof:*
If $x\ne y$ then $y = x+k$, with $k\in \Bbb{Z}^*$
And $|x-y| = |k| \ge 1$, thus no two distinct integers verify this relation
If $xRy$ and $yRz$ that means that $x=y=z$ thus $xRz$ also. 
So yes the relation is transistive

Comment: Thanks, i understand that it is transitive but how woud you show this